# Refresh content in Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Im loading dynamic content into an InfoWindow in a map.  When I close the infowindow and reopen it the content is the same (hasn't updated to the latest values).  Is there an easy way to force the infowindow to load its content each time it is opened?

Comment: How are you updating the values that you're talking about?

Comment: It's essentially an RESTful API call.  Content is delivered as text via a URL.

Comment: I should add i'm using api V2 for the time being.  Unfortunately we can't upgrade atm, however it is planned for the future.

Answer (score 2):

How about assigning a class/ID to the elements you want to update inside the InfoWindow. And update the HTML of those elements when you have new data.

Make sure you create the InfoWindow (`new InfoWindow()`) only once. When you want to hide the infoWindow use `infoWindow.close()` and to show it, use `infoWindow.open()` instead of creating new instances of infoWindow each time.

Comment: One InfoWindow thats content is populated when its clicked is a good idea.  Though if the same one is opened and closed multiple times in a row it won't be updated.  I really don't want to be updating via an ID or class selector, I thought it would be easy enough to just reload the content.  Its simply calling a URL.  If it was a webcam img that updates every minute, the first time you open it that would be the only image you'd see until the page is refreshed regardless of whether you closed the popup or not.

Comment: In API v2 you cant create an infowindow like this.  you can get the maps instance of the GInfoWindow however that seems almost useless.